# java.io.NotSerializableException even if i implement "Serializable"

Tags: java, android, exception, serialization

I have a little problem:
I wanted to test serialization on android (using eclipse) and found an example how to do it.
I know I need to implement "Serializable" in the class I want to serialize, I already did that and always get a java.io.NotSerializableException exception. Here's the code:

```
public void Button(View view) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
ser test = new ser();
    test.x = 204;
    test.y = 2843;
    test.speed = 12;
    test.direction = 1343;
    test.a = 493;
    test.b = 2323;
    test.c = 29489;
    test.d = 394;

    byte[] arr = serialize(test);

    ser res = (ser) deserialize(arr);
}


public static byte[] serialize(Object o) { 
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
    try {   
        ObjectOutput out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);      
        out.writeObject(o);                                       //This is where the Exception occurs
        out.close();     
        // Get the bytes of the serialized object    
        byte[] buf = bos.toByteArray();   
        return buf;    
    } catch(IOException ioe) { 
        Log.e("serializeObject", "error", ioe);           //"ioe" says java.io.NotSerializableException exception
        return null; 
    }  

}


public static Object deserialize(byte[] b) {  
        try {    
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(b));    
            Object object = in.readObject();    
            in.close();  
            return object;  
        } catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {   
            Log.e("deserializeObject", "class not found error", cnfe);   
            return null;  
        } catch(IOException ioe) {  
            Log.e("deserializeObject", "io error", ioe);    
            return null; 
        } 
    } 

class ser implements Serializable {
    float x, y, speed, direction, a, b, c, d;
}
```

I hope you can help me, I don't know what I did wrong...

Edit: my imports are:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutput;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
```

Comment: Look into Android Parcelables, its probably what you really want to use.

Comment: as answered/commented below, calling `Button(null)` is working as expected: no Exception and getting the correct values in `res`. Must be the environment...

Comment: How are you testing this? Do you use the amulator, do you deploy to an actual device? What version of emulator/Android are you using? There are differences between the different Android incarnations (like Cyanogen vs Stock Android etc).

Comment: I used both: an emulator (2.1 and later a 2.2 emulator) and a real phone (htc desire; 2.2.0), when I debug it doesn't matter how I do it, there is always the same result.

Answer (score 9):

Well, does your serializable object have any refferences to other non-serializable objects? If so the `java.io.NotSerializableException` will be thrown because of that. In order to be able to serialize you must have your class implemnent `Serializable` AND all dependencies it has be of type `Serializable` (i.e. implement Serializable) as well.

The exception message should tell you if such a non-serializable dependency exist:

It should say something like "java.io.NotSerializableException: NonSerializableClassName"

Update: as per Bozho's comment, I didn't notice that in fact your class does not have any non-serializable dependencies.

Comment: Yep, my bad, I didn't scroll all the way to the bottom, didn't see that the "ser" class is in there as well. I'll update my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Or is there another way to serialize a class?
All I want to do is sending a class like this with bluetooth and it only allows byte arrays...

Comment: @user1059863 you can use non-standard Java serializing libraries, like Kryo (http://code.google.com/p/kryo/). It doesn't ask you to implement java.io.Serializable, and sometimes it's faster and compacts better than standard Java Serialization

Answer (score 6):

The only thing I can think of is that the classes you are running are not the ones you have written - e.g. you haven't compiled the newer version.

I can't reproduce the problem with a simple java program.

Initially I thought you may have implemented `sunw.io.Serializable` rather than `java.io.Serializable`, but it extends the io class, so it should work even with it.

Comment: +1 that's a good point, there's more than one Serializable interface.

Comment: it appears sunw.io.Serializable extends java.io.Serializable, so I'm editing that point

Comment: Or is there another way to serialize a class?
All I want to do is sending a class like this with bluetooth and it only allows byte arrays...

Answer (score 4):

I've got the answer from below link, even though I can't understand the whole thing.
[why does this simple serializable object throw NotSerializableException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9747448/why-does-this-simple-serializable-object-throw-notserializableexception)
Be cause your inner class is not static, so to exist as a serialized thing, it will need the instance of the outter class and an activity is not serializabled. Make Tester a separate class or make it a static inner class.

Answer (score 2):

From your code it is not clear. But if you have defined "ser" as an inner class of some other non serilizable class (in your case probably it is "Activity" which is not serilizable) then either define that parent class also as serializable or do not define "ser" as inner class.

[Serialization of inner classes (i.e., nested classes that are not static member classes), including local and anonymous classes, is strongly discouraged for several reasons.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serial-arch.html)

Answer (score 2):

Old question, but would add my solution because I recently had a similar issue.

Solution, make sure your class `ser` is not a nested class. The built in Java serialization would fail without error if your class is nested in a non-implemented-serialized parent class.

So move the `ser` class implementation to it's own file `ser.java` and the serialization should now work.

Answer (score 1):

I broke my head with this.
Issue my code had was that I was not deleting my .ser file before I write the new object. My purpose is to write (serialize) ArrayList of locations and deserialize them. This I do when I get new location. As I could not append the objects I have chosen to write the complete List so I have to delete the .ser file everytime before I write the new List. Error it shows was not pointing to the actual problem.
Make your -ser fresh and clean before you write something to it.

Answer (score -1):

I know I'm a bit late but I noticed you don't have a serialVersionUID, something like `private static final long serialVersionUID = 7536482295622776147L;` at the top of your class, also(although it shuoldn't matter, it might help) try separating your variables, so:

```
class ser implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7536482295622776147L;
    float x;
    float y;
    float speed;
    float direction;
    float a;
    float b;
    float c;
    float d;
}
```

Once again, I'm a little late, but this question has thousands of views, and you haven't picked an answer, so maybe this will help someone.